# Arduino Switch and LED dimmer code

Tags: arduino, led

I have to make a program where a switch causes an led to change brightness each time the switch is clicked. The code below causes the LED to change brightness as needed but it does not stop changing if the switch is held down. I need it to only change once each time the switch is clicked. How do I make it change once when clicked and not loop through the other brightnesses?

const int ledPin = 10;

```
int brightness = 0;
boolean up = 1;
int steps = 0;
int inpin = 2;
int reading;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (inpin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  do{
    reading = digitalRead(inpin);
  }while (reading != HIGH);


    analogWrite(ledPin, brightness);
    delay(1000);
    if (up) 
    {
      brightness = brightness + 63;

    }
    else {
      brightness = brightness - 63;
    }
    steps = steps + 1;

    if (steps == 4)
      { 
        up = !up;
        steps = 0;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the brightness has been changed, wait for the switch to be released.